# Xcode XIP = non installed?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

During an attempt to reinstall `Xcode9` from scratch I decided to use the `XIP file` download from the [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) website.

I opened the archive, moved it to the Application folder and launched it. No problem, aside from the issues I was trying to solve that are still there ...

Now I go to the App Store and I see that Xcode results as non-installed.
What should I do?
I am running it on a MacBook Pro 15" from 2016 with macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: its .xip file not xib. right?

Comment: Yes, sorry ... `XIP`file.

Comment: Its all because you have installed from Apple site from Mac app store. that is why it is not showing like that. It directly downloaded from portal. if you want that it must not show as Not Installed in app store then install from app store again :).  No issues if you use the same as it is.

Comment: Great! Indeed it downloaded all the night from App Store and now it is working properly. Do you think I can use different versions of Xcode together? This 9.1 is giving me so many troubles and here https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/search/label/Xcode?&max-results=7 it even says that 9.1 is not considered a stable version.

Comment: I am downloading the `XIP file`from the previous links for 9.0 (where playgrounds were not broken and 8.3.2 (as it was all fine then!). I suppose I will just drag and drop the app icon into the Applications folder. Is it then that I have to say 'keep both versions' ? With other softwares I do the renaming trick but I think this should not be done in this case. Or could I ?

Comment: Of course you can. you need to download different versions from portal link 
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple version all together. just be carefull when installing after download, it will prompt to replace. "do not replace" but "Keep both versions". I am also using 4 different versions for compatibility checks. :)

[image]

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks!

Comment: if it worked then please you mark it correct. It will helps others too. :)

Comment: Done! It kept saying me that as I had less than 15 reputation I could not do it ... then now it worked :)